# Calculate autcorrelation of circular data?

Tags: python, c++, shell

I need to calculate autocorrelation for big circular data as follow:

Autcorrelation= sum from t=1 to N-K (x(t) – mean(x))*(x(t+k) – mean(x))/variance
mean=arctan2(sin(x),cos(x)), 
a= (x(t) – mean(x)) and b= (x(t+k) – mean(x))  needs to be correct in the sense of circular data with the following conditions:

if (x(t) – mean(x))>=-180 and (x(t) – mean(x))<=180
then a= (x(t) – mean(x))

elif (x(t) – mean(x))<-180
then a= (x(t) – mean(x))+360

else  (x(t) – mean(x))>180
then a= (x(t) – mean(x))-360

same is the case with b and variance is also periodic variance.

I am not sure how can i do this by using python?

Comment: Try using the [pycircstat](https://github.com/circstat/pycircstat) toolbox as a first step. You can use the `pycircstat.descriptive.corcc(sample1, sample2)` function, where sample1 is`vector[0:-lag_length]`, and sample2 is `vector[lag_length:]`, where vector is your vector of samples. If you use this library, you can also get a confidence interval, allowing you to say whether or not the autocorrelation at that lag length is significantly different from 0.

Comment: I have ASCII file with time in 1st column and angles in 2nd column, how can i incorporate this file in code.

Comment: Try 'numpy.loadtxt` to open the ASCII file, then pass the columns of the resulting array to `corcc`. Are the samples spaced uniformly in time? E.g. one sample every hour? If they aren't, an autocorrelation of an arbitrary lag t can't really be computed.

Comment: Yeah it is uniformly spaced. One sample each sec.

Comment: Were you using pip or a similar package manager?

Comment: Yeah i am using pip.

Comment: See if you can get help with the installation issues, maybe from the pycircstat people if the error you're getting is something strange that hasn't been encountered by someone else before... if you're doing analysis of circular data, having that library will save you a fair amount of headache.